# Google OAuth & API: blank login because localhost is not "whitelisted"

Tags: api, oauth

**Error (inspected from html):**

details: "Not a valid origin for the client: http://localhost:3000 has not been whitelisted for client ID 830959654564-inlhib5r4afjbm4ebt1e43gt07bpvve5.apps.googleusercontent.com. Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and whitelist this origin for your project's client ID."
error: "idpiframe_initialization_failed"

**Problem:**
Tried using localhost:3000 and my local ip address given from React.
I've tried clearing the cache. I've tried using other browsers.

[Blank Google OAuth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Iclo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well still no real solution but I created a new project and have reached no problems yet.

Answer (score -1):

For me, this only worked when I created a project directly from https://console.developers.google.com/.

The project I created "inline" at https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in never seemed to see the origin config.